# Minimize integral of functional

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima, calculus-of-variations

I want to find the non-decreasing, positive-everywhere (except at $x=0$), twice differentiable function $g$ which minimizes the following integral of a functional of a function: $$ \int_0^\infty g'(x) e^{-x} \ dx $$ subject to the following constraints: $g(0)=0, g(1)=1, \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} g(x) = +\infty, \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} g'(x) = +\infty$.

Any ideas for that? It seems that the standard Euler-Lagrange equation cannot be used because it would require that $x e^{-x} = 0$ which is of course impossible (let alone the three-constraint structure of this instance).

If convenient, I might potentially be ready to suppose that $ \int_0^\infty g_0(x) e^{-x} \ dx $ converges for the minimizer functional $g_0$ that satisfies the above constraints (e.g., really, any polynomial) but that might not yield optimal results in the full generality of the above problem, so I don't want to assume that out-of-the-box.

Comment: Hoe do you know a minimiser exists?

Comment: @copper.hat, seems like I forgot one constraint, $g$ must be increasing, twice differentiable. So, $g'(x) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$g(x)=\int _0^x f(t)dt.$$

The constraints are now: $0=0,\;\int_0^1 f(x)dx=1$ and $\int_0^\infty f(x)=+\infty$.

There could be many $f(x)$'s that minimize the integral, but here I am showing one possible $f(x)$ that minimizes it into $-\infty$.

Let:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1& (x < 1)\\
 -k& (1\le x\le 2)\\
 e^{x/2}& (x>2)
\end{cases}
$$

where $k$ is some constant for which we can take an arbitrarily large positive number.

This function obviously satisfies the first and the second constraint. Also, if we set $k$ to diverge slower than $e^{x/2}$, $f(x)$ satisfies the third constraint as well.

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-x}dx=\int_0^1 e^{-x}dx + \int_1^2 -ke^{-x}dx + \int_2^\infty e^{-x/2}dx=-(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{e^2})k+1-\frac{1}{2e}$$

$k\rightarrow+\infty$ then this diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: You're right; I'm sorry, I forgot to add more constraints to make sure this doesn't happen. Basically, $g$ should be increasing (non-decreasing), so that $g'(x)\geq 0$. Thus, if $g$ is expressed as an integral, it should be the integral of a non-negative function. (My problem really arises from a natural interpretation, so it's not always sure what is the minimum viable constraint set)